# How to make a custom progressbar in Android?

Tags: android, custom-controls, progress-bar, android-custom-view

What would be the best way to make somthing looking like this:

[image]

The text on it needs to be customizable, not only numbers, some strings too, depending on context.

From what I see it:

1. Create a custom `View` and within `onDraw` perform all the calculations and text alignment.
2. Style or extend a horizontal `ProgressBar`.

What do you think ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Extend ProgressBar ... override onDraw()

The primary reason for this is that all of the primary methods are already there and the first rule of object-orientated programming is code-reuse means don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Perhaps this method crossed with a Custom view including the overridden ProgressBar for your text & labels and what-nots.

Comment: Yes, this answer is the best. After reading it, did a bit of search and found this: http://colintmiller.com/2010/10/how-to-add-text-over-a-progress-bar-on-android/