# I realized a custom progress bar, but I want to improve that

Tags: android, android-view, android-progressbar

I realized a custom progress bar, and to do that I have extended a View. This progress bar is filled in base of some value received from a thread, moreover this view also contains a vertical line that change position related to pression button, a counter that indicate the position of the vertical line. And the shape of progress bar is a triangle rectangle.

In my extendev view I implemented this method :

```
public void setPowerBar(int Power)
    {
        pbIndex = 0;


        invalidate();
        requestLayout();

    }
```

this is the ondraw :

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    int width = ((pbIndex-20) * pb_i[0].getScaledWidth(canvas.getDensity())) / 180;
    int height = pb_i[0].getScaledHeight(canvas.getDensity())-(((pbIndex-20) * pb_i[0].getScaledHeight(canvas.getDensity())) / 180);

    dst.set(0, height, width, pb_i[0].getScaledHeight(canvas));

    canvas.drawBitmap(pb_i[0], 0, 0, null);

    canvas.drawBitmap(pb_i[1],null,dst,null);



    float dim = (pb_i[0].getScaledWidth(canvas.getDensity()));
    float step = dim/180;
    float xPos = ((orangePower-20)*step);

    canvas.drawLine(xPos, 0, xPos, pb_i[0].getScaledHeight(canvas), paintLine);

    canvas.drawText("" + orangePower, (dim / 2), pb_i[0].getScaledHeight(canvas), textPaint);

}
```

where

- pbIndex is the power
- pb_i[0] is the background image

This is the result :
[image]

Can you help me to improve my implementation ?

**Problem list:**

1. I have to optimize the code with @pskink suggestion.
2. I want to add some animator, because I want much fluidity
3. The ram consumption
4. The vertical line appears different on different device.

   ```
       paintLine = new Paint();
       paintLine.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FD8F40"));
       paintLine.setAntiAlias(true);
       paintLine.setStrokeWidth(7);
   ```

In particular the stroke width appears different

---

***Second implementation :***
in my layout xml I insert this :

```
 <com.example.canvastest.PowerBar
                android:id="@+id/power_bar"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:max="200"
                android:progress="0"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:maxHeight="12dip"
                android:minHeight="12dip"
                />
```

Then I add this drawable :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <clip>
            <bitmap android:src="@drawable/pb_0" />
        </clip>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <bitmap android:src="@drawable/pb_100" />
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Then I extend progressbar and its ondraw method :

```
@Override
    public synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        float dim = (canvas.getWidth());
        float step = dim/180;
        float xPos = ((orangePower-20)*step);

        canvas.drawLine(xPos, 0, xPos, canvas.getHeight(), paintLine);

        canvas.drawText("" + orangePower, (dim / 2),canvas.getHeight(), textPaint);
    }
```

But I have two problems :

1- when the progress is 20 the progress bar must be empty
2- the background is white and not the @drawable/pb_0
3- I have to insert some animator inside ondraw method

---

Comment: why dont you use a normal `ProgressBar` view?

Comment: @pskink Hi :) Because this progress bar also contains a vertical line that change position related to a button pression, a counter that indicate the position of the vertical line. And the shape of progress bar is a triangle rectangle. I add some more information in the first post :)

Comment: so no need for a custom View, use custom progress Drawable (`ProgressBar#setProgressDrawable`)

Comment: it's all day that I try to find how can I customize the progressbar to obtain the same result, but i can't.. @pskink : So i need to extend progressbar, right ?

Comment: no you should use `ProgressBar#setProgressDrawable` with your custom `Drawable`: `A Drawable is a general abstraction for "something that can be drawn."` a sample implementation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30873744/2252830)

Comment: But if I don't extend the progressbar how can I add the text and the vertical orange line ? I have to add the handle of it to the drawable ? :)

Comment: have you seen the link i posted?

Comment: No, i'm reading now :)

Comment: An ulterior question : when should I extend a View ?

Comment: when you need some custom actions, not for drawing progress bar (or drawing whatever which cannot be drawn by a Drawable)

Comment: ok, and why not extend progress bar ? :D For example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929062/how-to-make-a-custom-progressbar-in-android . I know i'm boring but I think that I can learn much from you. You are very clear :) Thanks a lot !
P.s : are there some book on that argoument ?

Comment: i see you are stubborn: ok you can extend `ProgressBar` but `setProgressDrawable` is for some purpose, it is not a mistake they wrote it

Comment: no I only ask :) In reality I was trying to extend drawable, I have to implement in it the function to move the vertical line and change test, and I think that I have to load two drawable : empty and full progress bar. 

I'm studyng the answer in the link that you have posted before :)

Comment: My first progress bar use 40mb of ram and the consumption grows :/ now I have some problem to add all function to the drawable and to add to it image from the resources .. Tomorrow I tell to you what I do :)

Comment: 40mb of ram? you mean 40 kb?

Comment: I test the above progress bar  in an simple application :
1 activity, 1 thread that generate 30hz data and setprogress bar, two buttons one for increment the orange vertical line position and one to decrement.

And the ram amount was 40mb

Comment: @pskink Hi :) I have edited the first post and ondraw methof of my custom view. Now I want to report the above behaviour in an drawable or in a custom progress bar.. But I don't understand in what way can I do :(

Comment: i have no idea: what is 40? 40 what? what is blue triangle and what is orange vertical line?

Comment: This progress bar is filled in base of some value received from a thread, moreover this view also contains a vertical line that change position related to pression button, a counter that indicate the position of the vertical line. And the shape of progress bar is a triangle rectangle

Comment: @pskink I did some edit in my code, and now I use some yours suggestion. But I also have some problems.

Comment: see [this](http://codeshare.io/I6pgl)

Comment: thanks :) But one question : in what way can I change the "orangePower" variable ? If I implement a setter method inside class D in what way can I call this from my activity ?

Comment: just call  drawable.setOrangePower(xxx)

Comment: oh wonderful :) I continue to study your code, is much clear than mine :D

Answer (score 1):

Please check another `drawBitmap` method of canvas [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Paint)).

For instance:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    // VIEW_WIDTH & VIEW_HEIGHT is the size of your progress bar, MAX_POWER is the max value of the Power
    int width = (Power * VIEW_WIDTH) / MAX_POWER;
    Rect dst = new Rect(0, 0, width, VIEW_HEIGHT);
    // only need one bitmap
    canvas.drawBitmap(pb_i[10], null, 0, null);
}
```

Comment: if I use drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint),
bitmap is the full progress bar (is a triangle rectangle png),
but if I set the dst the image will be stretched ?
I want to show background png (empty progress bar) and only part of full png .

Comment: You can specify the `Rect src` (The subset of the bitmap to be drawn) if possible.

Comment: I update the first post, and I'm trying to use "another drawBitmap method of canvas"

Comment: Why not to calculate the `Rect dst` based on the `Power`?

Comment: Now i'm doing in this way 
int width = (pbIndex * pb_i[0].getScaledWidth(canvas.getDensity())) / 300;
        int height = pb_i[0].getScaledHeight(canvas.getDensity())-((pbIndex * pb_i[0].getScaledHeight(canvas.getDensity())) / 300);

dst.set(0, height, width, pb_i[0].getScaledHeight(canvas));

pbIndex is the power
pb_i[0] is the background image

Comment: with code at my "EDIT5" inside first post the progress bar load itself in base of the power. Now I have to change : the progress bar have to start from 20 and not from 0; I have to optimize the code with @pskink suggestion.

Comment: OK, go ahead. If you want the progress bar start from 20, just modify the Rect as needed.

Comment: I edited my first post :) Now is much clear :) Thanks a lot for the help :)